# Clean list or list of lists of all None or Empty lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to implement a definition that will remove all None objects from a list or nested list of lists.

Example:

```
_list = [0,0,1,None,12, ""]
```

Return:

```
_result = [0,0,1,12,""]
```

Or if the input is a nested list of lists:

Example:

```
_list = [[1,2,None],[2,3,None,2],[2,3,None,None,""],[None,None,None]]
```

Return:

```
_result = [[1,2],[2,3,2],[2,3,""]]
```

Of course I am not sure what the incoming structure will be (depth of lists) or if some of them will contain all None values (in that case i want to remove the empty list as well).

i did see some examples here but they are all mostly list comprehension or iteration examples and none of them can handle deeper lists. All help will be appreciated. 
I am in IronPython 2.7.

Thank you,

Comment: Are you also removing the lists?

Comment: Do you want to preserve the initial list or should it be modified in place?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, if removing nulls from a list results in an empty list i would like to remove the empty list as well.

Comment: @jpmc26 i would like to preserve the original list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple recursive function will clean out your nested lists of `None`s as well as empty lists (originally or due to removal of `None`s):

```
def clear_list(l):
    out = []
    for ll in l:
        if ll is None:
            continue
        if isinstance(ll, list):
             ll = clear_list(ll)
             if not ll:
                 continue
        out.append(ll)
    return out
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def remove_None(_list):
    while None in _list:
        _list.remove(None)
    for element in _list:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            remove_None(element)
```

I hope this may help you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a recursive function that uses a list comprehension:

```
def clean_list(a_list):
    return [obj for obj in [clean_list(obj) if isinstance(obj, list) else obj
                for obj in a_list if obj is not None] if obj != []]

_list1 = [0,0,1,None,12, ""]
print(clean_list(_list1))

_list2 = [[1,2,None],[2,3,None,2],[2,3,None,None,""],[None,None,None]]
print(clean_list(_list2))

_list3 = [[1,2,None],[2,3,[4,None,"",5],6],[7,[[[8,[None],"test"],None]]]]
print(clean_list(_list3))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 12, '']
[[1, 2], [2, 3, 2], [2, 3, '']]
[[1, 2], [2, 3, [4, '', 5], 6], [7, [[[8, 'test']]]]]
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe this works. Try it with ``[[1,2,None],[2,3,None,2],[2,3,None,None,""],[[None, None], None,None,None]]``. The OP said the nesting is unlimited.

Comment: You're right. I missed the part at the end about arbitrary amounts of nesting — and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You also have an empty list left over in the second output, which the OP explicitly states should be removed.

Comment: @jpmc26: Ah, another detail I missed...and since you pointed it out have addressed in latest version of my answer.